# Swing Dialog Window is not visible on Run [WindowBuilder]

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm new to Java swing development, here I'm developing a simple desktop application Using WindowBuilder on eclipse (Mars). But I'm not able to see even boiler code dialog window popping up while Running my app in eclipse. However If I create SWT application window it show up on Run.

Here is my Swing dialog boiler code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class UploaderDlg extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UploaderDlg dialog = new UploaderDlg();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public UploaderDlg() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        {
            JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
            okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        }
        {
            JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Can someone please help me knowing what's wrong with it?

Comment: *"new to Java swing development, .. developing .. Using WindowBuilder"* That is a very sub-optimal approach. Learn how to use the API before relying on automagic drag and drop GUI designers that take all the control.

Comment: It seems it is fine. I've copy pasted your code into fresh project and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the file name -> open with -> windows builder.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for suggestion though it's working fine on preview from WindowBuilder but when I run class file using right click on file -> Run As -> Java Application, doesn't show up the UI.